# MS Project 2016 updating Actual Cost figures for Cost Resources that are set to accrue at the end of the task

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I am having an issue where MS Project 2016 is prorating the actual cost figures for cost resources that have been set to accrue at the end of the tasks. I have tried everything I can think about and the software continues to prorate the figures. For example, I have changed the Default Fixed Cost Accrual to End in Options, and I have also deselected the Actual costs are always calculated by Project option.

I can remember it working before when updating without prorating the actual cost figures.

Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Calvin

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, I'm not sure how you have set up your cost resources.  So I'm going to walk you through an example I have that works for me.

I have a cost item that has capital expenditure on equipment.  Go to Resource | View | Resource Sheet.  Once in the resource sheet, I add my resource by adding Resource Name "myEquipment".  I have two columns that I need exposed, Type and Acrrue At.  By default Type is set to "Work" and Acrrue At is set to "Prorated".  I change Type to "Cost" and Accrue to "End".  You might be tempted to add the Cost column and add a cost at this point, but you will not be able to because now this cost resource has to be tied to the end of a task.  Here is how it looks so far...

[image: Resource Sheet View Setup]

Now you need to go to the Task Usage view by going to Task | View | Task Usage.  Once you are in the Task Usage view, you will need the Cost, Actual Cost, % Complete, Duration, Start, Finish, Actual Start, and Actual Finish to visualize this example.

On the pane on the right, you will need Cost and Actual Cost.  You can change what you see by right clicking on the right pane and choosing your options.  In my example I also changed the timescale to show months.  You can play around with this to get what is needed for your particular schedule.

[image: Task Usage View Setup]

Next step is to add the cost resource "myEquipment" to a task.  I will add it to line 4 in my schedule.  After the "myEquipment" is added to the task, right click on the task (not the resource) and choose to "Information".  Once in the Task Information box go to the Resources tab.  Next to your cost resource go to the Cost column and add the cost amount.  Here I added $1,000.  Click OK after completing this step.

[image: Cost Resource Setup in Task Information]

You Should be able to see that the $1,000 was added to December even though the task spans from end of November to middle of December.

[image: Cost Seen in Right Pane with correct cost to Cost Resource]

Cost will not incur until you either enter 100% or an Actual Finish Date. The % Complete column will not accept anything less than 100%.  You can see the Actual Cost column populated once I entered 100% complete.

[image: Actual Cost Column Updated after 100% complete]

Comment: Thank you for the response; however, I did have my cost resources setup right. I think it was the way I had Microsoft project options set where I had project to calculate actuals. I have unticked that box and it seemed to resolve the issue. However, it occurred again on another task with a cost resource. I will continue to troubleshoot the issue.